# How to show a UIWindow over the keyboard but under a UIAlertView

Tags: ios, uiwindow

I want to show a `UIWindow` over the keyboard but then allow the `UIAlertView` shown when asking for permission to "Use Your Current Location" to show above the window.

Setting the window's `windowLevel` to `UIWindowLevelAlert` shows it above the keyboard but then the alert view shows below the window. So, `UIWindowLevelAlert` must be a higher window level than that of the alert view.

Answer (score 4):

Setting the window's `windowLevel` to `UIWindowLevelStatusBar` does what I want in iOS 6.1. But, this is weird because, according to Apple's documentation, `UIWindowLevelStatusBar` should be above `UIWindowLevelAlert.` Will this also work in 5.0, 5.1, and 6.0? I'm having trouble testing those on the simulator because my Internet is *really* slow.

Comment: I came across an odd situation on iOS 7. Using `UIWindowLevelAlert - 1` is not enough to ensure the window is behind the alert. I found that `UIWindowLevelAlert - 4` is required.

Comment: @ThomasW: I've run into the same issue. `UIWindowLevelAlert - 4` is janky as hell, but it's the only thing that works.

Answer (score 0):

UIWindowLevel is a CGFloat so you could assign an intermediate value like so: First determine which window is the keyboard window from the array [UIApplication sharedApplication].windows. Then,

```
window.windowLevel=(keyboardWindow.windowLevel+UIWindowLevelAlert)/2.f;
```